# Velvetiness meaning

Tags: single-word-requests

What meaning does the word *velvetiness* have and what would be be a suitable synonym for it in the next sentence?

> This was as near as I could get, in conversation with Emily, to a description of the peculiar exasperation, velvetiness, and mockery, of which Bosinney's manner had been composed.

Comment: "Velvetiness" means having the attribute of being "velvety".  "Velvety" means an appearance or sensation (literal or figurative) of velvet fabric.  "[Velvet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velvet)" is an exceedingly smooth, soft, relatively lightweight fabric.  A milkshake may be velvety, or a person's voice (or a skirt).  (The word does appear to be a bit out of place in the above description, as you would not normally consider "velvety" to be compatible with exasperation and mockery.)

Comment: Thank you! Would you say I could replace it with 'silkiness'? Is is something like 'smooth-tongued'?

Comment: "Silkiness" is not a perfect synonym, but is close.  I can't say what sense the author intended, though.

Comment: Velvet is smooth with a short nap (fuzzyness) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nap_%28textile%29 Silk is smooth with basically no nap whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth an extended quote from the source, "The Forsyte Saga":

> He had merely increased his dislike and mistrust for this young man,
>   who had tired him out with his politeness, and in whose manner he now
>   certainly detected mockery.
>
> The fellow was sharper than he had thought, and better-looking than he
>   hoped. He had a "don't-care" appearance that James, to whom risk was
>   the most intolerable thing in life, did not appreciate; a peculiar
>   smile, too, coming when least expected; and very queer eyes. He
>   reminded James, as he said afterwords, of a hungry cat. This was as
>   near as I could get, etc

Velvet has a very soft texture, and Bossiney's manner is extremely polite - "smooth" is often applied to such people. It is this smoothness and surface softness that is being described.

As a possible peripheral issue, the apparent softness of velvet is often (in English literature) contrasted with an underlying hardness or strength. The phrase "an iron fist in a velvet glove" is the classic. Describing Bossiney's manner as velvety, combined with his mockery, suggests that the surface manner is just that - surface.